# one desktop per monitor

Tags: display

It is possible to configure a desktop per monitor in Ubuntu 12.04 ?

If I enable 'simple desktop' in catalyst driver, one of my two screens is blank.
When I move my mouse in the blank screen, I have a cross.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is EOL and OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years. VTC as `not reproducible`.